# Find element of an array that appears only once in O(logn) time

Tags: algorithm

Given an array `A` with all elements appearing twice except one element which appears only once. How do we find the element which appears only once in `O(logn)` time? Let's discuss two cases.

1. Array is always sorted and elements are in sequential order. Let's assume `A = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]`, we want to find `3` in `log n` time because it appears only once.
2. When the array is not sorted and the elements are not in sequential order.

I can only come up with a solution of using the XOR operator on the binary representation of the integers as explained [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXWjCgbL01U), and at the end, the binary string will represent the element which appears only once because duplicates will cancel out. But it takes `O(n)` time. How can we do better than that?

Comment: There are two interpretations to *find element*: a) know its index b) know its value. Prove that *expected number of operations needed grows slower that the problem size **n*** is impossible for either 1 or 2 from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the elements are sorted (i.e., the first case you mentioned) then I believe a strategy not unlike [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/binary_search) could work in **O(logN)** time.

Starting from the left endpoint in a sorted array, until we encounter the unique element, all the index pairs `(2i, 2i + 1)` we encounter along the way will have the same value. (i.e., due to the array being sorted) However, as we go towards the right endpoint of the array, as soon as we consider an array that includes the unique element, that structure of "same values within `(2i, 2i+1)` index pairs" will be invalid.

Using that information, a search algorithm similar to binary search can find out in which half of the array the unique element is. Basically, you can deduce that, "in the left half of the array, if the values in the rightmost index pair `(2i, 2i+1)` are the same, then the unique value is in the right half". (i.e., with the exception of the last index on the left half-array being even; but you can overcome that case with various `O(1)` time operations)

The overall complexity then becomes `O(logN)`, due to the halving of the array size at each step.

For the demonstration of the index notion I mentioned above, see your own example. In the left of the unique element(i.e. `3`) all index pairs `(2i, 2i+1)` have the same values. And all subarrays starting from index 0 and ending with an index that is to the right of the unique element, all index pairs `(2i, 2i+1)` have a correspond to cells that contain different values.

Unless the array is sorted, though, since you'd have to investigate each and every element, I believe any algorithm you may come up with would take at least `O(n)` time. This is what I think will happen in the second case you mention in your question.

Comment: This contains one helpful insight (values at 2i & 2i+1 differ → right of singleton) and one misconception - what would be the significance of ordering or uniform differences?

Comment: Yeah, this was from my earlier days in StackOverflow. Thanks @greybeard , for commenting on it and bringing it to my attention once again. I tried to improve my answer in a way that removes the puzzling stuff about the uniform differences. Hope it helps any future viewer of the question.

Answer (score 2):

using [Haroon S' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849674/find-element-of-an-array-that-appears-only-once-in-ologn-time#comment70884364_41850203) this is the solution which I think is correct, given the constraints for time.

```
class Solution:
    def singleNonDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        low = 0
        high = len(nums)-1
        
        while(low<high):
            mid = (low+high)//2
            if(mid%2==0):
                mid+=1
            if(nums[mid]==nums[mid+1]):
                # answer in second half
                high = mid-1
            
            elif(nums[mid]==nums[mid-1]):
                # answer in first half
                low = mid+1
        
        return nums[low]
```

Comment: This just depends on identical values being next to each other - the elements don't need to be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case this is impossible, as to make sure an element doesn't repeat you need to check every other element.

From your example, it seems the array might be a sorted sequence of integers with no "gaps" (or some other clearly defined sequence, like all even numbers, etc). In this case it is possible with a modified binary search.

You have the array [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6].

You check the middle element and the element following it and see 3 and 4. Now you know there are only 5 elements from the set {1, 2, 3}, while there are 6 elements from the set {4, 5, 6}. Which means, the missing elements is in {1, 2, 3}.

Then you recurse on [1,1,2,2,3]. You see 2,2. Now you know there are 2 "1" elements and 1 "3" element, so 3 is the answer.

The reason you check 2 elements in each step is that if you see just "3", you don't know whether you hit the first 3 in "3,3" or the second one. But if you read 2 elements you always find a "boundary" between 2 different elements.

The condition for this to be viable is that, given the value of an element, you need to be able to calculate in O(1) how many different elements come before this element. In your case this is trivial, but it is also possible for any arithmetic series, geometric series (with fixed size numbers)...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a O(log n) solution. I have no idea how to solve it in logarithmic time without the constraints that the array is sorted and we have a known difference between consecutive numbers so we can recognise when we are to the left or right of the singleton. The other solutions already deal with that special case and I couldn’t do better there either.

I have a suggestion that might solve the general case in O(n), rather than O(n log n) when you first sort the array. It’s not as fast as the **xor** solution, but it will also work for non-integers. The elements must have an order, so it is not completely general, but it will work anywhere you can sort the elements.

The idea is the same as the k’th order element algorithm based on Quicksort. You partition and recurse on one half of the array. The time recurrence is T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n) = O(n).

Given array x and indices i,j, representing sub-array x[i:j], partition with quicksort’s partitioning method. You want a variant that partitions x[i:j] into three segments, x[i:k] x[k:l], x[l:j] where all elements in the first part are smaller than the pivot (whatever it is) all elements in x[k:l] are equal to the pivot, and all elements in the last segment are greater than the pivot.

(you might be able to use a version that only partitions in two, or explicitly count the number of pivots, but with this version is easier to work with here)

Now, if the middle segment has length one, you have your singleton. It is the pivot.

If not, the length of the segment that has the singleton is odd while the other is even. So recurse on the segment with the odd length.

It doesn’t give you worst case linear time, for the same reason that Quicksort isn’t worst case log-linear, but you get an expected linear time algorithm and likely a fast one at that.

Not, of course, as fast as those solutions based on binary search, but here the elements do not need to be sorted and we can handle elements with arbitrary gaps between them. We are also not restricted to data where we can easily manipulate their bit-patterns. So it is more general. If you can compare the elements, this approach will find the singleton in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This solution will find the element in the array that appeared only once but there should not be more than one element of that type and the array should be sorted. This is Binary Search and will return the element in O(log n) time.

```
var singleNonDuplicate = function(nums) {
  let s=0,e= nums.length-1
  while(s < e){
    let mid = Math.trunc(s+(e-s)/2)
    if((mid%2 == 0&& nums[mid] ==nums[mid+1])||(mid%2==1 && nums[mid] == nums[mid-1]) ){
      s= mid+1
    }
    else{
      e = mid
    }
  }
  return nums[s] // can return nums[e] also
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a O(log n) solution for that. The reason is that in order to find which element is appearing only once, you *at least* need to iterate over the elements of that array once.

Comment: I am new to algorithms. But if array is sorted, can we do this: Split the array in half, let say LeftArray and RightArray. In this case LeftArray with 6 elements and RightArray with 5 elements. If first two elements of right array are same, it means that "lonely integer" is in RightArray because left array is evenly distributed. Else it's in LeftArray and we can do the same divide and conquer strategy till we find the element. No?